# Measure both sides of an AC and DC circuit

Tags: oscilloscope, rectifier

So I have recently begun messing with diodes and there use in converting AC to DC. What I am curious in trying to do is to hook up my dual channel oscilloscope on bother DC and AC side to view the save form both sides generate. My question is this, is this safe to do, could I damage my oscilloscope by having separate channels measure the voltage on either side of the bridge.

Below is an example of what I would like to try.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2v6hG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible (likely, even). Most oscilloscopes have a common ground between channels, and common with earth. If you put two probes as you've shown above, the 12.6VAC in series with a diode will pass between the two probe grounds, which would be unfortunate (it could damage the probes or the oscilloscope).

For power supply work, I use a Tektronix [TPS2024](http://www2.tek.com/cmswpt/psdetails.lotr?cs=psu&ci=13304&lc=PT-BR) which has four isolated channels- isolated from each other, and isolated from earth.

Comment: Yeah that is a little more then I want to spend on an oscilloscope. I have recently purchases [Owon PDS5022T](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007T6XNCA/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). Admittedly I connected the DC side to one channel and only the ground of the second channel to one of the outputs on the transformer. The connection only lasted about 2 seconds before I realized what I did and pulled the whole thing apart. The oscilloscope appears undamaged.

Comment: That's only a two channel scope, so this doesn't help you, but it's sometimes practical to measure a non-ground-referred signal using two probes (and two channels) in a differential mode (maybe select A-B math or something like that depending on the particular oscilloscope).